# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'int'>

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, input, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1010, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2]),  return_sequences=True))
#model2.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars)),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(101 , activation= 'softmax'))
algorithm = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001,beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(optimizer=algorithm, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

By considering the solutions for similar questions, I have changed dtype of y from float32 to float64, kfcg_a is of float64 only.

```
print(type(kfcg_a))
print(type(y))
print(kfcg_a.dtype)
print(y.dtype)
```

it replied with

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
float64
float64
```

still error persists Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'int'> for model.fit

```
history=model.fit(kfcg_a,y.shape[1], epochs=100)
```

is it problem regarding versions of tensorflow and keras, I am not getting which versions are compatible to solve the problem, please cooperate to resolve issue.

Comment: why are you passing y.shape[1] as the second parameter of fit?

Comment: I want to pass 101 , y.shape[1] is 101 itself...let me replace it by 101

Comment: Yes sure but I asked WHY, why do you want to pass 101 as labels? That makes no sense.

Comment: thanks sir, I recognized my mistake, i thought you are talking about dense layer...just now understood error from model.fit, instead of y, i had passed y.shape[1] which is 101....it was obvious to get error... silly mistake....corrected..its working now...  thanks ..